# Proving that $f_n(\alpha_{n+1}) > 0$

Tags: sequences-and-series

We have that : $ f_{n}(x) = 2x - 2 + \frac{\ln(x^2+1)}{n}$

and : $ f_{n}(\alpha_{n}) = 0 $

Where :  $ 0 < \alpha_{n} < 1$

and they asked us to prove that : $f_{n}(\alpha_{n+1}) > 0$

and to prove that $ \alpha_{n} $ is a geometric series.

Comment: Just a thought, but maybe it would be a good idea to switch to $t=1-x$ instead of $x$ ... Perhaps it would be easier ... And why did I think of this? Because as $n$ gets larger, the roots get closer and closer to $x=1$.

Comment: @MattiP. okay, i got you .. but how can we reach the goal (proving that inequality) with this? please more explanation .. or give it a try, because i have no idea how can i do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$f_n$ is differentiable on $[0,1]$ and

$$
f_n'(x) = 2 + \frac{2x}{n(x^2+1)} > 0
$$

so $f_n$ is (strictly) increasing on $[0,1]$ and since $f_n(0) = -2 < 0$ and
$f_n(1) = \frac{\ln 2}{n} > 0$ there exists a unique $0 < \alpha_n < 1$ such that
$f_n(\alpha_n) = 0$. (In fact, $f_n$ is a strictly increasing bijection from $[0,1]$ to
$[-2,\frac{\ln 2}{n}]$ and thus its inverse $g_n$ is a strictly increasing bijection from $[-2,\frac{\ln 2}{n}]$ to $[0,1]$.)

Now for all $x$ in $]0,1]$ you have $\ln(x^2 + 1) > 0$ s0

$$
f_{n+1}(x) < f_n(x)
$$

so in particular

$$
0 = f_{n+1}(\alpha_{n+1}) < f_n(\alpha_{n+1}).
$$